# Any idea how to get this kind of format?

Tags: formatting, symbols, lists, enumerate, enumitem

Any idea how to get this kind of format? I'm struggling to get a consistent indentation after the section names (0.1, 0.2, etc)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you post the text as in copy/paste format? As no one want to type the content...

Comment: Sure! Like so??

0.1 a. The odd positive integers.
b. The even integers.
c. The even positive integers.
d. The positive integers which are a multiple of 6.
e. The palindromes over {0,1}.
f. The empty set.

0.2 a. {1, 10, 100}.
b. {n| n > 5}.
c. {1, 2, 3, 4}.
d. {aba}.
e. {ε}

Comment: Just to be clear, I just mean the format in general. I don't expect you guys to type out the symbols and all that!

Comment: it is just a standard latex enumerate layout as far as I can see. It _always_ helps if you put a small complete document in the question, to allow people to test answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to me like the screenshot could have been produced with the help of the `enumitem` package and its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional -- Times Roman text and math font

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{spenumerate}{enumerate}{2} % 'spenumerate' -- short for 'special enumerate'
\setlist[spenumerate,1]{label=\bfseries \thesection.\arabic*}
\setlist[spenumerate,2]{label=\bfseries \alph*.}

\begin{document}
\begin{spenumerate}
\item 
  \begin{spenumerate}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \item d
    \item e
    \item f
  \end{spenumerate}
\item 
  \begin{spenumerate}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
    \item D
    \item E
    \item f
  \end{spenumerate}
\end{spenumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

The "standard"* configuration method for setting the enumeration label format is redefining `\labelenumi` (top level), `\labelenumii` (nested level), etc. Sticking to that basic method gives

```
\documentclass{article}
% \theenumi is \arabic{enumi}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textbf{0.\theenumi}}
% \theenumii is \alph{enumii}
\renewcommand\labelenumii{\textbf{\theenumii.}}
%
\begin{document}

\noindent Hello there. This line shows the left margin.
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item odd
  \item even
  \item even positive
  \item multiples
  \item pals
  \item empty
  \end{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item alpha
  \item bravo
  \item charlie
  \item delta
  \item echo
  \item foxtrot
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I don't know that your "0" refers to, but you probably want it to give some other counter value.

Note * "Standard" in the sense that it is the style of the built-in document classes. List environments like "enumerate" aren't defined in basic LaTeX., but in the document class.